# Yii2: widget wbraganca Dynamic Forms Only saves one value submitted to db

Tags: forms, dynamic, yii, yii2, widget

I'm trying to save various instances of a field using the dynamic form widget. The problem I'm having is that after I submit it only saves the last value at input.

[image: This is how the widget looks in my form view.]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Facilidades a realizar y costo estimado:</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
         <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
            'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
            'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
            'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
            'limit' => 4, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
            'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
            'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
            'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
            'model' => $modelosfacilidades[0],
            'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
            'formFields' => [
                'Descripcion',
                'precio',
            ],
        ]); ?>

        <div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
        <?php foreach ($modelosfacilidades as $i => $modelofacilidad): ?>
            <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Descripción de facilidad y precio</h3>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php
                        // necessary for update action.
                        if (! $modelofacilidad->isNewRecord) {
                            echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelofacilidad, "[{$i}]id");
                        }
                    ?>

                    <?= $form->field($modelofacilidad, "[{$i}]Descripcion")->textArea(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($modelofacilidad, "[{$i}]precio")->textInput(['placeholder' => '$']) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .row -->

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
    </div>
```

This is a function Gii generated at my form model for the field that receives the data.

```
 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getFacilidadesARealizar0025s()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FacilidadesARealizar0025::className(), ['id_0025' => 'id_asda_pa_0025']);
}
```

And this is the actionCreate controller class:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new AsdaPa0025();
    $modelosfacilidades = [new FacilidadesARealizar0025()];

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->cuerdas= $model->propia + $model->usofructo + $model->arrendada;
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        $modelosfacilidades = Model::createMultiple(FacilidadesARealizar0025::classname());
        Model::loadMultiple($modelosfacilidades, Yii::$app->request->post());

        //valida los modelos
        $valid = $model->validate();
        $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelosfacilidades) && $valid;

        if ($valid) {
            $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                    foreach ($modelosfacilidades as $modelofacilidades) {
                        //Aqui le digo al controlador que id_0025 es igual al id de la instancia de la forma 0025
                        $modelofacilidades->id_0025 = $model->id_asda_pa_0025;
                        if (! ($flag = $modelofacilidades->save(false))) {
                            $transaction->rollBack();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_asda_pa_0025]);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        }

       // $model->file = 'uploads/' . $model->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $model->imageFile->extension;

       // if ($model->save()) {
        //    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
          //  return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_asda_pa_0025]);
     }
     else{
      // return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id_asda_pa_0025]);

      return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'modelosfacilidades' => (empty($modelosfacilidades)) ? [new FacilidadesARealizar0025] : $modelosfacilidades

    ]);

     }


   }
```

I would appreciate any help! I can't seem to find the answer to my problem anywhere.

Comment: can you confirm the names of the inputs when you generate more than one description and price fields do they appear like `ModelName[0]['description'], ModelName[1]['description']`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how do I confirm this?

Comment: just look up into the html source for that using chrome inspector look into the field names

Comment: I've never used Google inspect since I'm fairly new to web programming but I think I found what you mean. In Element it says: <div class="form-group required has-success field-facilidadesarealizar-0-0-precio">
<label class="control-label" for="facilidadesarealizar-0-0-precio">Precio</label>
<input type="text" id="facilidadesarealizar-0-0-precio" class="form-control" name="FacilidadesARealizar[0][precio]" placeholder="$" aria-invalid="false">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>     I think that it stays ModelName[0] but was not able to verify because i dont know how touse google inspect

Comment: see this link https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/ , try first adding some duplicates by clicking `+` sign and then check the name for the 2 price inputs , make sure they are `"FacilidadesARealizar[0][precio]` and `"FacilidadesARealizar[1][precio]`

Answer (score 0):

1)Make sure that Active form has the same id as the formId in your DynamicFormWidget:
`<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>`

2)Change `[new FacilidadesARealizar0025()] to [new FacilidadesARealizar0025];`

3)    After     `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {`

add

```
\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
return Yii::$app->request->post();
```

and make sure that all your FacilidadesARealizar0025 model data is submitted. This helps you determine whether the problem is in your form or your create function. If not all your data is posted then focus on your form. I hope this helps